# Mongo Error: $sort stage must have at least one sort key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
  let sort = {}
    if (req.params.orderby === 'pricelow') {
        sort.price = 1
    }
    if (req.params.orderby === 'pricehigh') {
        sort.price = -1
    }

 Products.aggregate([
        { $match: {} },    // This is your query
        { $skip: skip },   // Always apply 'skip' before 'limit'
        { $limit: limit }, // This is your 'page size'
        // { $sort: sort }
    ])
```

I am trying to sort through my data, and if url parameter `orderby` exists, I want to pass in sort in my mongodb aggregate. However, when there isnt any sort condition I want to keep it empty, like no sorting condition. As far as I understand from the error I get, which is :

```
MongoError: $sort stage must have at least one sort key
```

sort condition cant be empty. Is there a way to get around this by using aggregation in mongodb? How can I just get the results as there were no sort condition, like default.

Comment: I think you need to specify the _sort key_ (the error message says so). The Sort Key is the field you want to sort on; see syntax at [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do those types of things then try this.

```
    let aggregateQuery =[
            { $match: {} },    // This is your query
            { $skip: skip },   // Always apply 'skip' before 'limit'
            { $limit: limit }, // This is your 'page size'
        ];
    
    let sort = {}
    if (req.params && req.params.orderby === 'pricelow') {
        sort.price = 1;
    aggregateQuery.push({$sort:sort});
    }
    if (req.params && req.params.orderby === 'pricehigh') {
        sort.price = -1
    aggregateQuery.push({$sort:sort});
    }

 Products.aggregate(aggregateQuery);
```

I Hope It Will Help You.